# Parameters for opening pdf files not working in electron

Tags: electron

I am trying to open pdf files in an iframe by also using parameters to control how the pdf is opened. They work great on the website, but they don't seem to work on electron: the pdf is opening inside the iframe, however, the zoom level specified by the 'view=fitH' does not seem to work in electron. Is there any way to make the parameters work in electron too? This is the code that I am using.

```
<iframe src='./res/test.pdf#page=1&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=fitH' frameborder="0" style="width:72.5%;height:95%;position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"></iframe>
```

Update:

I will try to offer more details of what I'm trying to do. I'm building the app from macOS Sierra and the end goal is to have a local app for windows which can be used instead of the online app when there is no internet connection. I am using the following command to build the app:

```
electron-packager ./ --platform=all --arch=all --overwrite --asar
```

However, the pdf is not fitting the width of the iframe as it should, but is instead zoomed out like in the following image:

[The actual result - you can see that the pdf is zoomed out a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elBjo.png)

I will try to build the app from windows and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "'view=fitH' does not seem to work"? It works identically to Chrome and Edge from what I can tell. Show an image about your desired layout perhaps.

Comment: Yes, they work perfectly fine in all browsers, I don't have a problem with that. However, in the windows app generated by electron, the PDF will have a random zoom when it is opened in the iframe and will not automatically fit horizontally inside the iframe as it does in the browsers. Unfortunately, I can't share any images, but let me know if something is not clear and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: I've tested with the code below and see no difference to browsers. That's why I've asked. How do you load it? That may make the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I was breaking the rule:

> [Individual parameters, together with their values (separated by & or #), can be no greater then 32
>   characters in length.](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

I am now using `page=1&toolbar=0&view=fitH` and it works like expected now.

I don't know why it worked in browsers even though I was using more than 32 characters, but I guess there is an exception to every rule.

Answer (score 0):

I see this working just the same way as in browsers

*main.js*

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
    }
  })
  win.loadURL(`${__dirname}/pdfargs.html`)
})
```

*pdfargs.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src='./res/test.pdf#page=1&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=fitH' frameborder="0" style="width:72.5%;height:95%;position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, pergy, and I apologise for the delay in responding. I had a different main.js, so I tried building with yours, but unfortunately I get the same result: the pdf opens in the iframe, but it is zoomed out. I'll update the question in order to provide more details about what I'm doing.